# When is locking necessary

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, consistency

Ok, I know this may sound quite stupid (and I'm afraid it is), but I'm not completely satisfied with the answer I gave myself so I thought it was worth it asking it here.
I'm dealing with an exercise about concurrency (in Java) which goes like this

> Given a solved Sudoku chart, determine, using a fixed number of threads running at the same time, whether the chart has been correctly solved, i.e. no violation of the canonical rules occur (a number must appear within its row, its column, and its block only once).

Now my question is: since the threads only have to perform "reads", gathering infos from the chart and elaborating them somewhere else, couldn't they work without worrying about concurrency? Chart's state is always consistent since no "writes" are performed, hence it's never changed.

Aren't locks/synchronized blocks/synchronized methods necessary if and only if there's a risk for resources' consistency to be lost? In other words, did I understand concurrency the right way?

Comment: Does "a fixed number of threads" rule out using a single thread?

Comment: Shared, mutable state needs to be protected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a fairly subtle question, not stupid at all.

Multiple threads that are reading a data structure concurrently may do so without synchronization, **only if the data structure has been safely published**. This is memory visibility issue, not a timing issue or race condition.

See section 3.5 of Goetz, et. al., *Java Concurrency In Practice*, for further discussion of the concept of safe publication. Section 3.5.4 on "Effectively Immutable Objects" seems applicable here, as the board becomes effectively immutable at a certain point, because it is never written to after it has reached the solved state.

Briefly, the writer threads and the reader threads must perform some memory-coordinating activity to ensure that the reader threads have a consistent view of what has been written. For example, the writer thread could write the sudoku board and then, while holding a lock, store a reference to the board in a static field. The reading threads could then load that reference, while holding the lock. Once they've done that, they are assured that all previous writes to the board are visible and consistent. After that, the reader threads may access the board structure freely, with no further synchronization.

There are other ways to coordinate memory visibility, such as writes/reads to a volatile variable or an `AtomicReference`. Use of higher-level concurrency constructs, such as latches or barriers, or submitting tasks to an `ExecutorService`, will also provide memory visibility guarantees.

**UPDATE**

Based on an exchange in the comments with [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows), I should also point out that the *safe publication* requirement also applies when getting results back from the reader threads. That is, once one of the reader threads has a result from its portion of the computation, it needs to publish that result somewhere so that it can be combined with the other reader threads' results. The same techniques can be used as before, such as locking/synchronization over a shared data structure, volatiles, etc. However, this is usually not necessary, since the results can be obtained from a `Future` returned by `ExecutorService.submit` or `invoke`. These constructs handle the safe publication requirements automatically, so the application doesn't have to deal with synchronization.

Comment: However the various reader threads also need to vote somewhere on whether their task fragment contributes to the overall success or failure of the Sudoku check. Which is a write…

Comment: Reporting and merging partial results doesn't necessarily have to involve writing to shared mutable state. An alternative, often preferable, is to return a results as a function value such as from a `Callable`. This is available to the thread coordinating tasks via a `Future`. See `ExecutorService.invokeAll`. This does involve handing off values between threads, but no additional locking is necessary.

Comment: That really depends on how inter-thread messaging is implemented, doesn't it? If you're going to invoke a memory barrier going one way, you're going to need something equivalent going back. (Mind you, since it's really a single bit — or more realistically a single byte or word depending on method used — there are a number of pretty efficient ways to do it.)

Comment: Right, there does have to be a memory barrier for the return values. In my comment above, this is encapsulated within `Callable` and `Future` (implemented by `FutureTask`). If the application uses these constructs, it doesn't need to do any synchronization of its own.

Comment: FWIW, I'd go with an `ExecutorService` too, but that's because pitching tasks to a thread pool (with a standard implementation) is _easy_ to code correctly and easy to calibrate to the hardware available.

Comment: Yup! Not only do the j.u.c libraries handle threading automatically, they also deal with the safe publication requirements as well. I've updated the answer with this information. Thanks for raising this point.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion your understanding is correct. Data corruption can only happen if any of the threads is writing on the data.

If you're 100% sure that no thread is writing, then it's safe to skip synchronization and locking...

EDIT: skipping locking in theses cases is the best practice!
:)

Comment: Actually, it is the best practice. Sharing immutable data among reading only threads is the best way not to mess up with synchronization issues, and provides the best performance :-)

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for pointing that out. I'm editing that last line.

Comment: But don't forget what Stuart Marks said in the first answer:  The immutable object(s) must be "safely published."  That means, insuring that no other thread can see the immutable data object(s) until it (or all of them) have been completely constructed.  There are subtle ways, (described in _Java Concurrency In Practice_) that a multi-threaded program running on a multi-processor machine can let one thread see an object as it was before some other thread finished constructing it.

Answer (score 1):

No need of Synchronizing the file if it is read-only.Basically lock is applied to **critical section**.Critical section is ,where different threads accessing the shared memory concurrently.
Since Synchronization makes program slow as no multiple threads access at same time so better not to use lock in case of read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a bunch of work to complete (check 9 rows, 9 columns, 9 blocks). If you want threads to complete this bunch of 27 units of work and if you want to complete the work without double work, then the threads would need to be synchronized. If on the other hand, you are happy to have threads that may perform a work unit that has been done by another thread, then you don't need to synchronize the threads.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do whether you want to avoid duplicating work, but just with how you schedule the work. It's trivial to statically schedule work that no work is repeated without any locking at all.

Comment: Indeed.  There might be a monte-carlo algorithm with a non-zero probability of duplicating _some_ work, but which completes, on average, with enough processors, in less time than another algorithm that guarantees to never duplicate work.

Comment: @voo In this simple example of checking validity of a sudoku board, yes one can statically distribute the work amongst different threads and no locking is required. But in general, if each work unit takes different amount of time to complete, then it is not optimal to divide the work amongst threads statically. Some threads would be overloaded and some threads might not have enough work.

jameslarge, how do you deduce that duplicating work completes on average in less time than an algorithm that never duplicates work? In general, I would say that duplicating work is a BIG NO.

Comment: @anonymous There are quite a few problems where the additional communication and synchronization overhead are by far worse than some threads accidentally duplicating work. Monte carlo simulations as James mentions being a good example of it. It's all just a question of how much you duplicate and how high the communication cost would be to avoid it. No hard and fast rule there.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario where `Thread1` writes some data and then a bunch of threads need to read this data doesn't require locking if done properly. By properly I mean that your SUDOKU board is an immutable object, and by immutable object I mean:

- State cannot be modified after construction
- State is not actually modified via some reflection dark magic
- All the fields are final
- 'this' reference does not escape during construction (this could happen if during construction you do something along the lines `MyClass.instnce = this`).

If you pass this object to the worker threads you are good to go. If your objects don't satisfy all these conditions you still may run into concurrency problems, in most cases it is due to the fact that JVM may reorder statements at will (for performance reasons), and it might reorder these statements in such a way that worker threads are launched before sudoku board was constructed.

Here is a very nice article about [immutable objects](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue176.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Abstract**

For a thread to be guaranteed to observe the effects of a write to main memory, the write must *happen-before* the read. If write and read occur in different threads, that requires a synchronization action. The spec defines many different kinds of synchronization actions. One such action is executing a `synchronized` statement, but alternatives exist.

**Details**

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> Two actions can be ordered by a *happens-before* relationship. If one action *happens-before* another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.

and

> More specifically, if two actions share a happens-before relationship, they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order to any code with which they do not share a happens-before relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to those reads.

In your case, you want the reading threads to solve the right sudoku. That is, the initialization of the sudoku object must be visible to the reading threads, and therefore the initialization must *happen-before* the reading threads read from the sudoku.

The spec defines *happens-before* as follows:

> If we have two actions x and y, we write `hb(x, y)` to indicate that `x` *happens-before* `y`.
>
> - If `x` and `y` are actions of the same thread and `x` comes before `y` in program order, then `hb(x, y)`.
> - There is a happens-before edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).
> - If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

Since reading occurs in a different thread than writing (and not in a finalizer), we therefore need a synchronization action to establish that the write *happens-before* the read. The spec gives the following exhaustive list of synchronization actions:

> - An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
> - An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.
> - The write of the default value (zero, false, or null) to each variable synchronizes-with the first action in every thread. (Although it may seem a little strange to write a default value to a variable before the object containing the variable is allocated, conceptually every object is created at the start of the program with its default initialized values.)
> - The final action in a thread T1 synchronizes-with any action in another thread T2 that detects that T1 has terminated (T2 may accomplish this by calling `T1.isAlive()` or `T1.join()`)
> - If thread T1 interrupts thread T2, the interrupt by T1 synchronizes-with any point where any other thread (including T2) determines that T2 has been interrupted (by having an InterruptedException thrown or by invoking Thread.interrupted or Thread.isInterrupted).

You can choose any of these methods to establish happens-before. In practice, starting the reading threads after the sudoku has been fully constructed is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score -2):

From my point of view, locking is necessary if you write and this *writing* takes a long time to complete due to say network latency or massive processing overhead.
Otherwise it's pretty safe to leave the locking out.

Comment: Even if the write operation takes two clock cycles or 1 nanosecond, locking is necessary when writing.

Comment: In theory that's correct. The thing is, that such write operations are done in 99% of all cases for in-memory storage medium, like `CHM` and write synch is provided out of the box, so you don't have to care of it by yourself. For all other cases you must do locking by hand, and I think the topic starter meant exactly that.

Comment: @injecteer: that's plain wrong. And your rule is inapplicable anyway: "a long time" doesn't mean anything concrete. I suggest you read Concurreny in practice, by Brian Goetz.